# WebpackDevServer crashing with Error: RSV1 must be clear

Tags: webpack, websocket, http-headers, webpack-dev-server, ws

In a new project that I set up, the webpack dev server initializes a websocket on my specified port and attempts to communicate reload commands etc. through the socket. The problem is, on specific ports (that I've used on past projects) the dev server crashes with the RSV1 error. I checked the buffer result from the first chunk that the websocket receives and it starts as follows:

```
GET /ws HTTP/1.1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

The first letter there corresponds to the proper value for the RSV1 bit to be flagged and the socket expects to have to decompress the chunk, but doesn't see that compression is enabled to it falls over. To me, this indicates that for some reason the websocket is pulling the connection request as a message into the socket. However, I can't seem to figure out why the socket is receiving this chunk. When I use a unique port, I get the data that I expect to see (base64 encoded string).

Does anyone have an idea why this is occurring?